# What is the meaning of 'to be recessed 0.2mm in area shown' in a drawing

Tags: articles

What is the meaning of  'to be recessed 0.2mm in area shown'  in a drawing

Comment: A recess is a shallow hole in a surface. This is say the depth of that hole should be 0.2mm and the hole should cover (be the shape of) the area being shown in the drawing.

Comment: It wouldn't be a hole, in the sense of creating an opening in the material. It would be an indentation, usually so that another piece will "sit" inside the indentation by 0.2mm.  This would be different from one piece attaching to the surface of the other or being able to pass through the other (hole).

Answer (score 3):

> Recessed
>   Attach (a fixture) by setting it back into the wall or surface to which it is fixed.
>   -- [Google Dictionary](http://www.google.com/search?q=define%20recessed)

This means it is an indent - like so:

───┐
         │  <- The wall
         │
      ┌┘
      │  <- is indented / recessed into the wall
      └┐
         │
         │
───┘

Zoom:

0.2mm
  ├──┤

┌──┘
  │
  │  <- is indented / recessed into the wall
  │
  └──┐

Bonus, extruded / protruding:

───┐
         │  <- The wall
         │
         └┐
            │  <- is protruding / extruded from the wall
         ┌┘
         │
         │
───┘

[Box shapes from unicode website, range 25, hex 2500 to 25FF](http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/unicode/unidata25.html)

Comment: +1 for the graphic wizardry, but to me they look like the wrong way round. To me, the wall is on the left, I'm looking from the right(ish), the top one is protruding, the bottom recessed. It's because your '<-- The wall' is pointing at the back side of the wall, not the face that the protrude/recess is pointing at.

Comment: @Frank, good point, looking at it again you're right. I will edit to make it clearer.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you very much. Your drawing is very easy to understand.